# Lost changes in git merge after marking a separate file as "resolved"

Tags: git, version-control, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution

I know it's a tricky subject so I will try to simplify thing as much as possible, tell me if we actually need more details about the changes involved.

So basically, using SourceTree, I had to conduct quite a simple operation, merge branch A into B (B originate from A). Let's says I had three files : 1,2 and 3, which were all modified in both branches. During the merge, I ran into a conflict on file 2, which I manually resolved marked as "resolved". I then pressed commit to let git handle the rest of the merge but itself.

Turns out now, a few changes that were introduced in A on file 3 were restored to the state they were at when B was branched out from A. This is extremely disturbing as there were no conflict involved on this file so git should have merged the changes too. Also, this file does not appear in the simplified logs, (even though i can see the changes using a direct command line diff between the two commit). 
Even worst, B as been merged into A later on, and now I cannot find these changes introduces on A anywhere in the file history.

How is it possible that git erased this commit without notifying me at any stages?

My only guess is that it could actually be a sourcetree problem, where marking a file as "Resolved" and then clicking commit to finalize might not the correct way to handle the process (should I manually ask git to restart the merge or something like that? It seems weird as git doesn't allow to commit if the merge state is not fully resolved).

However I would appreciate some hints here as it's extremly difficult to even notice these problem, and could be a huge issue for our company...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that the state of file 3 after the merge neither agreed with branch A nor with branch B?

Comment: No actually it was me not understanding properly the git flow. Source tree / git "Resolve with mine / theirs" will actually take the exact version for the FULL file, while my understand what that it would take this file code for the conflictual zone only.